# Entity Framework objectcontext ending prematurely

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity

Hello I am getting the error "ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection". When I run some methods from a wcf service. All of them use a new context object and most of them run without issue. However this one keeps giving the error above although several methods with similar implementations succeed several lines above in my code:

```
public CustomAuthentication.WebService.Application GetApplicationByUrl(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                using (AuthenticationEntities2 auth = new AuthenticationEntities2())
                {
                    Application app = auth.Applications.Where(a => a.Url.Contains(url)).FirstOrDefault();

                return app;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\r\n" + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

I also initially saw this error from vs "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server." So I thought it was an issue serializing objects in my wcf service. So I did some tracing on the service and discovered the error above. So now believe its entity related. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off lazy loading on your ObjectContext. Most probably your Application contains navigation properties which trigger lazy loading during serialization.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks Ladislav. Also I'm reading Lerman's book on em and she recommends just using poco's during wcf operations to eliminate many of these types of issues. I wonder what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @dave: Yes using POCOs in web services is the way to go. But even with POCOs you can still use lazy loading so be aware of it.